# What functions satisfy $f(x)+f(y-x) = g(y)$?

Tags: functions

What functions $f$ have the property that, for all $x$ and $y$:
$$
f(x) + f(y-x) = g(y)
$$
i.e., the sum does not depend on $x$?

Linear functions obviously this property: if $f(x) = ax+b$, then:

$$
f(x) + f(y-x) = ay+2b = g(y).
$$

On the other hand, if we look only at differentiable functions, then *only* linear functions have this property. By taking the derivative of the first equation as a function of $x$:

$$
f'(x) - f'(y-x) = 0 \iff f'(x)=f'(y-x)
$$

Since this is true for every $y$, $f'(\cdot)$ must be a constant function, so $f$ must be linear.

Are there non-differentiable functions with this property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put $y=x$ to get $f(x)+f(0)=g(x)$. Now verify that $h(x)=f(x)-f(0)$ satisfies $h(x)+h(y-x)=h(y)$. This is same thing as $h(x+y)=h(x)+h(y)$. There are discontinuous functions satisfying this equation. A continuous function $f$ satisfies the given property (that is to say the property stated in the question) iff $f(x)=ax+b$ for some constants $a$ and $b$.

Comment: The solution $f(x)=ax+b$ is for the original equation in  the question, not for additive functions.

Comment: Then **say so**.

Comment: This is what I was missing: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation so if $h$ is continuous, then $h(x) = a x$ for some constant $a$, which implies that $f(x) = h(x) + f(0) = a x + b$ for some constants $a,b$.